# list customactions and rights

Tags: permissions, custom-actions

we have a custom action for list settings, that requires ManageLists rights:

```
  <CustomAction Id="fear.is.the.path.to.the.dark.side"
                Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
                GroupId="Permissions"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Sequence="99"
                Title="$...;"
                Description="$...;"
                Rights="ManageLists">
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/Custom.aspx?List={ListId}" />
  </CustomAction>
```

and there is a code level check in Custom.aspx page for direct url typing:

```
    if (!list.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ManageLists))
        SPUtility.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, Context, "ErrorCode=" + ErrorCodes.UserIsNotAuthorized);
```

the problem is, even if the user has full control and code-level check passes when I directly navigate to the url,  SharePoint does not display the link in "List Settings".

Am I missing something ?

thanks!

Comment: Can I assume that you're deploying this as part of a feature and that the feature is activated?

Comment: yes, feature is activated. if the logged user is site admin then link is visible. but according to the documentation fullcontrol or design rights should be enough for the document library..

Answer (score 1):

I took your exact snippet and it works fine for a generic doclib (101), so you're either dealing with deployment issue or you're looking for it in a non-generic doclib (i.e. Site Pages...119 vs 101) or other lib type (i.e. Picture Library...109 vs 101).

Comment: I just want it to be visible in document libraries.. not the generic ones.. just the ones supposed to contain docs, xsls etc.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the **RegistrationID** value, because 101 represents the Document Library Content Type. For lists we have to use 100, this is a RegistrationID value for Generic list.

Comment: thanks.. But I want it to be visible only in document libraries, not any other list.

Comment: Change Sequence number from 99 to lower one and then deploy the feature. Because Custom Action will visible to user based on priority, mention in Sequence value.

Comment: The Sequence affects ordering priority not whether or not the CustomAction is displayed...you can make it 1 or 10000 and it will have zero impact on visibility, just order.